# Is there keyboard shortcut to deselect text on a mac?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut, keybindings

To select all text in Chrome or other apps I can use:

<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>

From a web search I found this potential shortcut to deselect text:

<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>

Sadly that doesn't work across all apps.

Is there a keyboard shortcut that can deselect text after I've selected all text with <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> ?

Comment: ⇧⌘A should work in _most_ apps, which ones are you trying?

Comment: @SilverWolf doesn't work in Chrome, Evernote, Terminal, I'm sure there are more. What does it work in?

Comment: There is no white space available to click in?

Comment: @JustinTanner It doesn't work in Terminal for me either, but Terminal is kind of a special case. I don't have Chrome or Evernote. Have you tried TextEdit, Pages, or the Notes app?

Comment: @SilverWolf for Notes it appears to do something else and yes Pages it does deselect, so there is one app that this works in so far.

Comment: @jmh clicking with the mouse will deselect, but I was looking for a keyboard shortcut.

Comment: oh sorry. I thought you were stuck! lol

Comment: @JustinTanner Sorry about Notes, I guess the shortcut wasn't as universal as I thought. In fact, many apps I'm trying out here don't do it either! (:

Answer (score 3):

It is app specific as to whether there is a keyboard shortcut for deselecting text.

The finder uses: Command + Option + A, while Pages uses Command + Shift + A, while Notes, Reminder, and Safari don't have an option.